# Identity column without index or unique constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just experienced a database breakdown due to sudden extradordinary data loading from disk.
I found the issue would arise when I attempted inserting into a log table with approx. 3.5 million rows. The table features an ID column set to IDENTITY, but with no indexes or unique constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IntegrationTestLog](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ident] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Thread] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Logger] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [varchar](max) NULL
)
```

Issue triggered by this line:

```
INSERT INTO IntegrationTestLog ([Ident],[Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@Ident, @log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)
```

There are possibly many other queries that will trigger it, but this one I know for sure.

Bear with me, cuz' Im only guessing now, but does the identity seeding process somehow slow down if an index is missing? Could it by any slight chance fall back to doing a MAX(ID) query to get the latest entry? (Probably not). I haven't succeeded in finding any deep technical information about the subject yet. Please share if you know some litterature or links to such.

**To solve the issue**, we ended up truncating the table, which itself took VERY long. I also promoted ID to be primary key.
Then I read this article: [Identity columns](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/identity-columns/) and found that truncate actually does touch the identity seed.

> A truncate table (but not delete) will update the current seed to the
>   original seed value.

...which again only led me to be more suspecious of the identity seed.

Again I'm searching in the dark - please enlighten me on this issue if you have the insight.

Comment: The `truncate` command on a table DELETES all the data on that table: records, clears the log file, resets the identity field. Basically `truncate` does a "table reset". On the other hand, the delete command, simply deletes all data, but does not clear the log file or reset the identity. The truncate `command` is much faster then running a delete command.

Comment: I found something related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365380/im-sql-server-should-i-create-an-index-for-an-identity-column-or-is-it-created. Hope it helps

Comment: The DELETE takes time because its going row by row writing the operation to the transaction log for rollback purposes. TRUNCATE does none of that. Still it took several minutes on this table to do TRUNCATE. On a similar table just minutes later, I truncated 11 million rows in seconds, but this other table did actually have a unique index ID.

Comment: The `IDENTITY` value is stored in the system tables so it shouldn't have to recalculate it using `MAX(id)` as you hypothesise. [Some details here](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/Sequences-Part-2-129205). Sounds like maybe you were blocked by something. Next time look at `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see what wait type(s) the process is getting.

Comment: What do you mean by database breakdown? What error?

Comment: LachlanB, in this situation a breakdown was the fact that the DB was so busy doing something that any insert/update/delete query would timeout, rendering virtually any application tied to this server useless.