# SQL Server : Identity column indexing

Tags: sql-server, identity

I have a table which has an identity column. There is no primary key in the table. I have to search the data on basis of identity column so I need that to be indexed.

I want to know if the identity columns are by default indexed or do I have to explicitly index this identity column?

Comment: No, you'll need to add an INDEX. I believe the question has been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4365380/314291)

Comment: If there is no PK on the table why wouldn't you just make the id column the PK?