# SQL Server : while Update querying is executing, cannot execute delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server

tbl_bettingdetails_DG Table Sturucture :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BettingDetails_DG](
    [BDDG_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BDDG_UserId] [int] NULL,
    [BDDG_Token] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BDDG_Data] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BDDG_TicketId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [BDDG_BetAmount] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [BDDG_WinLoseAmount] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [BDDG_BeforeAmount] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [BDDG_AfterAmount] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
    [BDDG_Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [BDDG_winloseDatetime] [datetime] NULL,
    [BDDG_CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [BDDG_NetWinLoseAmount] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_BettingDetails_DG_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BDDG_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BettingDetails_DG] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_BettingDetails_DG_BDDG_winloseDatetime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [BDDG_winloseDatetime]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BettingDetails_DG] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_BettingDetails_DG_BDCT_CreatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [BDDG_CreatedDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BettingDetails_DG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_BettingDetails_DG_tbl_MasterStatus] FOREIGN KEY([BDDG_Status])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tbl_BettingDetails_MasterStatus] ([StatusId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_BettingDetails_DG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tbl_BettingDetails_DG_tbl_MasterStatus]
GO
```

Stored procedure 1 :

```
    BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN TRAN
           UPDATE tbl_bettingdetails_DG 
           SET BDDG_BetAmount = 222222 
           WHERE BDDG_TicketId = 3489495541

           WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN                   
    END CATCH
```

Stored procedure 2 :

```
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
    BEGIN TRY 
        BEGIN TRAN

        DELETE t1 
        FROM tbl_BettingDetails_DG t1  
        WHERE BDDG_TicketId = 1231231232

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN   
        SELECT @ErrorMessage=CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    print @ErrorMessage

    END CATCH
```

I'm executing stored procedure 1 first, while it hasn't committed yet, I have 10 seconds time, then I executing stored procedure 2.

How come stored procedure 2 has to wait until stored procedure 1 execution has completed, only execute delete query? My delete query it is not same ticket ID, both query are don't have any relationship.

How to execute stored procedure 2 without waiting for stored procedure 1 to complete?

and i was tried add Non-clustered Index, it is working, and i send the screenshot as reference .
[image]

Comment: Is this Sql Server Express by chance?

Comment: SQL SERVER EXPRESS or SQL SERVER ENTERPRISE...BOTH SQL SERVER are facing same issue

Comment: you should add an index on `BDDG_TicketId ` so that queries don't have to scan all rows and encounter ones locked by other transactions for different tickets

Comment: @MartinSmith OK, let me try

Comment: @MartinSmith which Index i should create? Non-Clustered Index , Clusted COlumnsstore index or Non-Clustered COlumnStore index?

Comment: non clustered index

Comment: If you make your Id column a primary key, an index is created for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365380/

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, i just add the BDDG_TIcketID as a index, i was edited the post on top, and attached screenshot, it does not work, the issue is still there

Comment: How are you calling these sprocs?

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, u can look at the my table structure, BDDG_id is a primary key, and it is a clustered index, i execute those SP in SQL Management studio.

Comment: @MartinSmith oh martin, it is my misstake, it is working, after i create non-cluster index, it is no waiting any more...please write as answer, i will mark your post as answer..thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original table definition has no index on `BDDG_TicketId`.

This means that the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries both have to scan all rows to find matching ones for their `WHERE` clauses - and so will be blocked by `X` locks taken out and held by other transactions.

Add a nonclustered index on `BDDG_TicketId` so that the relevant ones can be identified efficiently without this contention.